# laravel view::share isn't passing data to view

Tags: php, twitter, laravel, laravel-4

I am using thujohn/twitter-l4 package to show tweets in my laravel app.

[Part of a tutorial that I have found](http://www.mackhankins.com/blog/laravel/simple-twitter-feed-with-caching-using-laravel-and-twitter-api) on setting this up calls for setting the view:share in the homeController:

```
public function __construct()
{       
    /*Get Tweets*/
    View::share('tweets', Helpers::twitterFeed('username', '1', false, true));
}
```

and a helper function like this:

```
public static function twitterFeed($screen_name='username', $count='1', $include_retweets='false', $exclude_replies='true')
{
    $twitterfeed = Cache::remember('twitterfeed', 30, function() use ($screen_name, $count, $include_retweets, $exclude_replies) {
        return Twitter::getUserTimeline(array('screen_name' => $screen_name, 'count' => $count, 'include_rts' => $include_retweets, 'exclude_replies' => $exclude_replies));
    });
    if(!empty($twitterfeed))
    {
        return $twitterfeed;
    }
    else
    {
        return array();
```

**I am substituting username for a real twitter id

The problem that I am having is that when I iterate over the tweets in my view, nothing is found.   I am not using the homeController for any other methods.  I though that the view::share should make the tweets available on any page, but I must be making a mistake.

view:

```
@if(!empty($tweets))
            @foreach($tweets as $tweet)
                <div class="twitter-block">
                    {{$tweet->user->name}} ({{Twitter::linkify('@'.$tweet->user->screen_name)}})
                    <p>{{Twitter::linkify($tweet->text)}}</p>
                    <span class="timeago" title="{{$tweet->created_at}}">{{ date('H:i, M d', strtotime($tweet->created_at)) }}</span>       
                </div>
            @endforeach
        @else
            <p>We are having a problem with our Twitter Feed right now.</p>
        @endif
```

Anyone see why the $tweets isn't making its way to my view? Is it because I am not utilizing the HomeController for anything else? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to `dd(Helpers::twitterFeed('username', '1', false, true));` in your controller to check if you have results?

Comment: @Jeemusu I did try that and nothing happened.  So that means that the view::share in the homeController.php isn't connected to the view, right?

Comment: I removed the View::share from the homeController.php and added it to my route.php file and the function works now.